# add a view using the broadcast receiver to the top activity which is running currently?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

Can i add a view to the top activity in broadcast receiver.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext
                            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
```

componentInfo.getClassName() returns the class name of the top activity running. I can also get the package name. Can I add a view or some animation on current top activity. I need the layout name in most cases to bind to it but I am not able to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok . i figured out . I started a service in the background , and then i got hold of the  WindowManager and then  inflated the view to be added . Then i used windowmanager.addView(inflatedView) .

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, it would be quite a security concern if you do. However you may be able to start a new activity that's on top of it and doesn't cover the entire screen? What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have you seen thrutu application . I you have installed the android application , then when you are on call there is a sliding drawer which which has some options . How can i have a activity which does not cover the whole screen ?

Comment: No, I haven't seen thrutu. If I had to guess I would say they are replacing the whole call activity. To have an activity that does not cover the whole screen, simply set numeric values to your top layout's layout_width and layout_height attributes.

Comment: No , they are not replacing in call screen activity . The sliding drawer of thrutu just comes on top of it and both the thrutu drawer as well as the in call screen activity which it partially covers is active .Basically while the thrutu drawer is on top , I am still able to access the buttons in call screen.

Comment: So I got it right the first time? The solution is not to add views to external activities -which should be impossible anyways-, but to show an activity on top of it that partially covers it. Is that right?

Comment: yes , but both the activities need to be active at the same time .The partial one and the one below it .